# How to set Parameters in Lightning Component controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm working on a lightning:select tag to display account names in the dropdown list, whenever I select an account from the list it shows all the opportunities but I want only account related opportunities for that I'm passing ID parameter to the apex controller but it's not showing anything.

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="BookFaircls"> 
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Opportunity[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="Id" type="ID"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> <lightning:select name="selectItem" aura:id="selectItem" label="" onchange="{!c.oppRecords}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.account}" var="acc">
    <option value="{!acc.Id}">{!acc.Name}</option>
    </aura:iteration</ligh‌​tning:select>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunity}" var="opp"> {!opp.Name} </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
 ({ 
        doInit : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var action = component.get("c.getAccountNames");
         action.setCallback(this, function(response){
         component.set("v.account", response.getReturnValue());
         }) 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
         }, 

        oppRecords : function(component, helper){ 
        var value = component.get("c.getOpportunityDetails");
        value.setParams({Id :component.get("v.Id")}); value.setCallback(this,function(res){ 

        component.set("v.opportunity", res.getReturnValue()); })
        $A.enqueueAction(value);
        }
 })
```

Comment: what you have tried , Shared the code.

Comment: @anu Next time updated the code in question itself .

Comment: Hi @anu, you can click the edit link the to bottom left of your post and add the code to your question directly, no need to post a new question.

Comment: As I see your doInit function there is no action.setParams method to set parameter.

Comment: I want setParams method in oppRecords method not in doInit and I need to pass setParams value to the Apex method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you missed the attribute `value=""`, you can't get the selected value. So you should mention the attribute `value="{!v.Id}"`in `lightning:select` component.

```
<lightning:select name="selectItem" aura:id="selectItem" label="" value="{!v.Id}" onchange="{!c.oppRecords}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.account}" var="acc">
    <option value="{!acc.Id}">{!acc.Name}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your code but still no opportunities getting.

Comment: @anu did you check  in the controller **component.get("v.Id")**  whether you getting the selected AccountId. Can you check your code again because I think it's working fine.

Comment: In component controller I'm setting the "Id" value here:
var action = component.get("c.getOpportunityDetails");
        action.setParams({
            Id : component.get("v.Id") 
        });

Comment: @anu - make sure you get the value in `console.log(component.get("v.Id"));` , if yes, check your apex controller.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting AccountId in the console but that accountId is not passing a parameter to apex controller method: here is my code is there any mistake I did? please help me
 
@AuraEnabled 
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityDetails(String id){
         List<Opportunity> opps = [select name from Opportunity where AccountId =:id];
         return opps;   
    }

Comment: thanks for your responses. I got the account related opportunities. great work